# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class connect

Tags: php, class, mysqli

when i try to create a class to connect to database 
i got this error

> > **Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class connect in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\include\config.php on line 11**

i created a class with a function connect with mysqli vars ,
but i didn't get a good result without errors.

**config.php**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
session_id("hassan");
session_start();

}
class connect {
var  $dbhost="localhost";
var $dbuser="root";
var $dbpass="";
var $dbname="projects";
var $dbport=3306;
var $mycon;
//error_reporting(0);
function contact(){
$con1=mysqli_connect($this->dbhost,$this->dbuser,$this->dbpass,$this->dbname,$this->dbport);
if(!$con1)
include_once "error.html";
mysqli_query($con1,"set names 'utf8'");

if($con1){
include_once dirname(__DIR__) ."/template/title.php";
$this->mycon = $con;
}
return $this->mycon;

}
}
$con= new connect();
$con->contact();
?>
<?php 

?>
```

any idea to fix it ? 
i tried many ways ..

Comment: we need to know what is line 11 and for which file. What you posted doesn't support the question/error.

Comment: in line 11 class connect {

Comment: in line 11 class connect { @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: You're including the file twice. Don't.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález it still give me an error

Comment: This code is obsolete. `var` should not be used to declare class properties and has been obsolete for at least a decade. Also, indent your code. This is a mess to read which makes debugging more difficult. Also, be sure to declare your methods as private, protected, or public. Be clear how this xcode is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are including the file twice, which is a mistake. The immediate fix is to do this:

```
if (class_exists("connect")) {
    //your code here
}
```

so your class will be declared once and at the next inclusion of the file, it will be skipped. But after you do this fix, you will need to review how, where and why this file is included or required. Make sure you are including or requiring it only once. [include_once](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.include-once.php) and [require_once](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.require-once.php) are your friends here. When you fixed the inclusions, you can avoid using the if I have given around your code.